# Check if sqlite.net 3.5 is installed

Tags: sqlite, registry, inno-setup

I need a check in my Inno Setup script if sqlite.net is installed! Which registry key
is to verify?

(setup package: http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.86.0/sqlite-netFx35-setup-x86-2008-1.0.86.0.exe)

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{02E43EC2-6B1C-45B5-9E48-941C3E1B204A}_is1
```

This is default Inno Setup registry key which is used for Uninstall option (in Control panel).

**{02E43EC2-6B1C-45B5-9E48-941C3E1B204A}** is GUID of installation.

You can use several values to get installation path, e.g. **Inno Setup: App Path** or **InstallLocation**